# How to optimize string copying (memory allocation)?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, stl

I'm making a program (think: something like [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/)) that, more or less, goes through a bunch of strings and ranks them according to some criteria.

I store the results in a `vector<SearchSuggestion>`, where the structure is currently defined as follows:

```
struct SearchSuggestion
{
    std::string path;
    int tag;
};
```

In my program, I copy the structures (and hence the string) around a lot, due to the need to manipulate lots of file paths and whatnot.

While this causes a noticeable but small delay in release mode, it **dramatically** slows down the debugging of my program (i.e., several-second pauses in between keystrokes). Looking for the cause, I see almost all of the time is spent with the following stack trace:

```
ntdll.dll!RtlCompareMemoryUlong()   
ntdll.dll!RtlpAllocateHeap()    
ntdll.dll!RtlAllocateHeap()     
ntdll.dll!RtlDebugAllocateHeap()    
ntdll.dll!string "Enabling heap debug options\n"()  
ntdll.dll!RtlAllocateHeap()     
msvcr90d.dll!_heap_alloc_base(unsigned __int64)     C
msvcr90d.dll!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl(unsigned __int64, int, const char *, int, int *)
msvcr90d.dll!_nh_malloc_dbg_impl(unsigned __int64, int, int, const char *, int, int *)
msvcr90d.dll!_nh_malloc_dbg(unsigned __int64, int, int, const char *, int)
msvcr90d.dll!malloc(unsigned __int64)
msvcr90d.dll!operator new(unsigned __int64)
MyProgram.exe!std::_Allocate<wchar_t>(unsigned __int64, wchar_t *)
MyProgram.exe!std::allocator<wchar_t>::allocate(unsigned __int64)
MyProgram.exe!std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_Copy(unsigned __int64, unsigned __int64)
MyProgram.exe!std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_Grow(unsigned __int64, bool)
MyProgram.exe!std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::assign(const std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> > &, unsigned __int64, unsigned __int64)
MyProgram.exe!std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >(const std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> > &)
MyProgram.exe!SearchSuggestion::SearchSuggestion(const SearchSuggestion &)
MyProgram.exe!std::_Construct<SearchSuggestion,SearchSuggestion>(SearchSuggestion *, const SearchSuggestion &)
MyProgram.exe!std::allocator<SearchSuggestion>::construct(SearchSuggestion *, const SearchSuggestion &)
MyProgram.exe!std::_Uninit_copy<SearchSuggestion * __ptr64,SearchSuggestion * __ptr64,std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> >(SearchSuggestion *, SearchSuggestion *, SearchSuggestion *, std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> &, std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag, std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag)
MyProgram.exe!stdext::unchecked_uninitialized_copy<SearchSuggestion * __ptr64,SearchSuggestion * __ptr64,std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> >(SearchSuggestion *, SearchSuggestion *, SearchSuggestion *, std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> &)
MyProgram.exe!std::_Uninit_move<SearchSuggestion * __ptr64,SearchSuggestion * __ptr64,std::allocator<SearchSuggestion>,std::_Undefined_move_tag>(SearchSuggestion *, SearchSuggestion *, SearchSuggestion *, std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> &, std::_Undefined_move_tag, std::_Undefined_move_tag)
MyProgram.exe!stdext::_Unchecked_uninitialized_move<SearchSuggestion * __ptr64,SearchSuggestion * __ptr64,std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> >(SearchSuggestion *, SearchSuggestion *, SearchSuggestion *, std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> &)
MyProgram.exe!std::vector<SearchSuggestion,std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> >::_Umove<SearchSuggestion * __ptr64>(SearchSuggestion *, SearchSuggestion *, SearchSuggestion *)
MyProgram.exe!std::vector<SearchSuggestion,std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> >::_Insert_n(std::_Vector_const_iterator<SearchSuggestion,std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> > *, unsigned __int64, const SearchSuggestion &)
MyProgram.exe!std::vector<SearchSuggestion,std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> >::insert(std::_Vector_const_iterator<SearchSuggestion,std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> > *, const SearchSuggestion &)
MyProgram.exe!std::vector<SearchSuggestion,std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> >::push_back(const SearchSuggestion &)
MyProgram.exe!Appender<std::vector<SearchSuggestion,std::allocator<SearchSuggestion> > >(const wchar_t *, _tfinddata *, void *)
MyProgram.exe!EnumMatches(const std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> > &, const std::vector<std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >,std::allocator<std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> > > > &, int (const wchar_t *, _tfinddata *, void *)*, void *, int)
...
```

So it's pretty obvious that it's the copying of `std::string` that's taking too long, probably due to poor locality of reference.

So now my question is simple:

#### How can I improve the performance of allocating a lot of small strings?

Comment: Try VS2010. With move semantics and small-string optimisations, I'm tempted to believe that it'll perform better.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The slowness of the whole IDE in 2010 (when added up) is worse than what I'm experiencing in my program, so that wouldn't really help the situation. :(

Comment: What exactly are `EnumMatches()` and `Appender()` doing? Knowing that may make it easier to come up with a suggestion to avoid copying the strings (for example, it might be possible and appropriate to cache the copies somewhere).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: `Appender` is just 4 lines -- it creates a `SearchSuggestion` from the given string and pushes the result into the `vector`. `EnumMatches` is, however, the main part of the program -- it enumerates a bunch of matches (determined from the given parameters) and calls the given callback for each one. Both of them do some string copying. There's also a `RankMatches` that isn't shown -- that one also does string copying, and returns a vector of pairs of suggestions with some other ranking data. I indeed probably *could* cache the strings, but that would make the program less modular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to stop putting them by value into the `SearchSuggestion` structure. Instead give every `SearchSuggestion` a handle to the `std::string` which represents the path.

```
struct SearchSuggestion {
  int pathId;
  int tag;
};
```

This will make the copying within the vector more effecient as it will just be copying around simple `int`s instead of complex `std::string` values.

You can then use an `std::map<int, std::string>` structure to map path id's into real path's.

Comment: ooooo... interesting idea! I could actually store a reference to the map too, to avoid passing an extra parameter... I'll try it out, thanks! +1 (Edit: Not sure if it's going to be a trivial change, because then I'd have to make sure I don't deallocate the backing store before the vector... will try, though.)

Comment: There are a few variants on this; the most aggresive uses one huge `char[]` and makes `pathId` a size_t offset into this array. The underlying theme is that you often don't need to _modify_ a string, the only change is assignment of a complete new value.

Answer (score 3):

You might try using Boost.Flyweight. I don't guarantee it'll work — the time saved from not copying the string might be spent checking if that string wasn't already stored — but you can give it a try.

Another option is to turn it into a `boost::shared_ptr<std::string>`. There's only a pointer that will have to be copied now (so the cost will be practically null), but now there's an added cost when actually accessing that string (but this might not be that big of a problem).

It shouldn't be hard to try out these two and see which one produces better results.

Comment: Sorry but I think both parts of your answer are duplicates of two other answers. :\

Answer (score 1):

The perfiest answer is: don't allocate and copy lots of strings. Use shared pointers to constant strings or symbols instead.

Malloc() and strcpy() are just slow, period, and copying a string is always going to be an O(n) operation. In realtime code it's better to just avoid allocations as much as possible.

Comment: Would that actually help though? It'd be a big design change, and I'm not sure if it's a great idea... shared pointers required an extra heap allocation anyway, and it doesn't seem like it's the *copying* that's the issue (as opposed to the allocation itself, specifically because it's in debug mode) so either way, I'd be having twice as many allocations as I need, with pretty bad locality of reference...

Comment: Also, I do have to mention: The number of times each string is copied is fixed (it's around a handful). But the *number* of strings is variable. And while I could avoid *copying* them, I can't avoid *allocating* them the first time (since there's path manipulation involved), so that could at most only make my program faster by a constant factor (somewhere around 2-5x), which is insignificant anyway, considering that my dataset is rather small right now and could grow easily by a much bigger factor.

Comment: @Mehrdad Jared has a nice example of what I meant by sharing pointers to strings, so I upvoted his answer instead. =)

Answer (score 1):

Try boost::flyweight:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/basics.html